# How to stress\load test sitecore azure indexes

Tags: azure-search

I wanted to know how to stress test the sitecore azure indexes(rebuilding of indexes).

Is there a methodology or a tool(like Jmeter or similar tool) to check how the index performs under heavy load.

Comment: Please clarify the following to help me answer: what sitecore version? Are you using PaaS or IaaS? Do you have Application Insights or can you enable this?

Comment: @Mark we are using Sitecore 8.2 update 3. It is on Azure PaaS environment. We have application insights enabled. Can we measure from application insights? If yes please let me know how. It would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor the performance of your index via Application Insights.

1. Open the Azure Portal
2. Open your Application Insights instance and click the Metrics tab
3. Change the Resource dropdown to your Azure Search service
4. Select the Search queries per second metric

If you need to generate load artificially, this can also be done via Application Insights under the Performance Tests tab. From there you can create a test which will generate load on the WebApp. You'll need to configure the test carefully to hit a page on the site that triggers a search.

Comment: Is it possible to get index rebuild time ?

Comment: Not that I know of, but could you just trigger a rebuild and time it yourself?